# Conflict between recyclerview scrollListener and my custom onTouchListener

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Hi I am using [DiscreteScrollView](https://github.com/yarolegovich/DiscreteScrollView) as a horizontal scrollable list, I implemented an onTouchListener to the recyclerView item to detect swipeUp and click to open the card but I seem to have a problem when I try to swipe in an angel (see picture).

[image]

It scrolls instead of swipeUp to open the card.

```
override fun onFling(
        e1: MotionEvent,
        e2: MotionEvent,
        velocityX: Float,
        velocityY: Float
    ): Boolean {
        val result = false
        try {
            val diffY = e2.y - e1.y
            val diffX = e2.x - e1.x
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight()
                        Log.d("swipe", "swipe right")
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft()
                        Log.d("swipe", "swipe left")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom()
                        Log.d("swipe", "swipe bottom")
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop()
                        Log.d("swipe", "swipe top")
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace()
        }

        return result
    }
```

My OnSwipeTouchListener to recognize the swipes on the card

Here is the [ScrollLayoutManager](https://github.com/yarolegovich/DiscreteScrollView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/yarolegovich/discretescrollview/DiscreteScrollLayoutManager.java) of the library

Any ideas how I can handle this that I can recognize this as a swipeUp and not start to scroll the recyclerview.

Thanks.

Edit :

I was using the GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() and the onFling method didn't get triggered so I looked if any other method is being called and saw that the onScroll method is being called. I just implemented the onScroll method of SimpleOnGestureListener and added the same code to recognize the swipes, now it works.